# Unable to restrict other IP's for SSH using AWS ec2 security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ip

I would like to allow only specific Public IP to use pem file (SSH) .
I have added my ip only for SSH but I am able to connect with the same SSH in different public ip or lets say different computer with different internet.

```
Edit inbound rules
Type
Protocol
Port range
Source
Description - optional
HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   -
HTTP    TCP 80  ::/0    -
POP3    TCP 110 0.0.0.0/0   -
POP3    TCP 110 ::/0    -
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   -
All traffic All All ::/0    -
POP3S   TCP 995 0.0.0.0/0   -
POP3S   TCP 995 ::/0    -
IMAPS   TCP 993 0.0.0.0/0   -
IMAPS   TCP 993 ::/0    -
SSH TCP 22  42.109.252.7/32 - //This is what I have added to allow myself only to use SSH
SMTP    TCP 25  0.0.0.0/0   -
SMTP    TCP 25  ::/0    -
IMAP    TCP 143 0.0.0.0/0   -
IMAP    TCP 143 ::/0    -
DNS (TCP)   TCP 53  0.0.0.0/0   -
DNS (TCP)   TCP 53  ::/0    -
HTTPS   TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0   -
HTTPS   TCP 443 ::/0    -
```

Actually I have a pem file available which I want that it should be accessible others only when I add their ip's from the AWS panel config of security group in inbound rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have a rule of all traffic from any IP in your security group list.

There is no specific ordering for security group rule evaluations so when this rule is the first evaluated you will find that a target IP is able to access any port on the EC2 host.

If you want to restrict IP addresses who can SSH to the host you will need to remove the following rules:

- `All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   -`
- `All traffic All All ::/0    -`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , Could you elaborate it bit more that if I remove "All traffic" what all can go wrong ?

Comment: If you remove this any traffic not included in the security groups will no longer be connectable. For example, you have not specifically added port `21` which is used with FTP. If you had an FTP server running on this any user could connect on this port. After removal this would not be possible. Regarding SSH only the specific IPv4 address mentioned in your question will be able to SSH to the server anymore

Comment: Thank you so much mate It worked I have been banging my head myself since morning ,You guys are awesome in this COVID-19 you are like office seniors mates  .
Thanks again

Comment: No problem, we're here to help. Have a great day :)